# Not Grasping Step in Checking a Diode is Off

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

I'm struggling to understand the solution for a circuit analysis problem regarding diodes. Starting from the circuit on the left (image at the bottom), the teacher argues as follows:

- Assume \$D_1\$ is on.
- The current going through \$D_1\$ is computed; as it is negative we have reached a contradiction.
- Assume \$D_1\$ is off i.e. we open-circuit at \$D_1\$.
- \$I_2\$ is computed. It has a value of \$3.1V/R\$.

Up until now I seem to understand everything, yet in the next step the teacher writes

> To check if our solution fits the assumption of \$D_1\$ being off, we calculate the difference of tension \$V_R=I_2R=3.1V\$. This voltage is greater than the value of the source \$V_1\$, implying \$D_1\$ must be cut off.

**Why does the tension \$V_R\$ being greater than \$V_1\$ guarantee us that \$D_1\$ is off?**

[image]

Comment: This is [your circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSlBm.png). That makes it pretty clear to me.